# OnRequestStart on coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

Is their away to force OnSessionstart to run again on OnrequestStart if needed.

I'm building a site where alot of variables are created based on a dynamic subdomain. So I'll want to check onRequestStart if the the domain is the same if not reset the session variables.

Does this make sense and is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer your first question, yes. You CaN call onSessionstart directly, like so:

```
<cfset onSessionstart()>
```

However, all that does is start the session and allows you to execute certain code whenever a new session starts. CF already automatically starts a new session when one is warranted.

Reading on it seems what you want to do is set domain specific session variables. That can be done any number of ways but probably the least "good" way to do it would be by calling the onSessionstart method again. The reason I say this is that whatever you are doing in the onRequestStart method, you could/should be doing in onSessionstart. That is, whatever info you have available to you in onRequestStart insofar as which domain the user is using is available in onSessionstart.

That and, you can set a session variable anywhere in the code of your site. It doesn't HAVE to be done in onSessionstart.

Comment: Seconded. If you are needing to check for session variable existence in `onRequestStart()`, I'd be wondering if something was implemented slightly suboptimally. Possibly it's not, but I'd sit down and have a think, anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

onSessionStart should be triggered by a different subdomain - those would be different cookies.

However, if code in the ColdFusion Application events needs to be shared or re-run, break them out into their own functions and run them from multiple events. This is how most frameworks run their "reinit" functions: application is init'ed when it starts, but also via URL. The shared function is called, not the original application event.

Comment: What if he is using domain cookies? I'm thinking the case of a m.mysite.com and www.mysite.com.

Answer (score 2):

personally I wouldn't be calling onSessionStart from within OnRequestStart as that could be really hairy when you have code in onSessionStart that you might not want to run everytime OnRequestStart fires. What I would do is just create a new method and just place it on the onSessionStart and onRequestStart methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just run onSessionStart() from within onRequestStart()? That will cause the code inside of onSessionStart() to fire. You are outside of the session creation lifecycle at that point, but the code will run.